# `__attribute__((destructor))` not running in some cases?

Tags: c, destructor, ld-preload

I am writing a toy malloc(3) implementation, loaded with `LD_PRELOAD`, as an exercise. I have  a function annotated with `__attribute__((destructor))` to dump a list of allocations and their status on exit for debugging purposes but I found it doesn't run in some cases. Specifically, it does run on locally-compiled code but not against system binaries like `/bin/ls` (on Arch Linux). A `constructor`-tagged function does work for both cases, though.

A simple repro of the problem is:

`main.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// compile with: clang -o main main.c

int main() {
    printf("main\n");
}
```

`wrap.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// compile with: clang -o wrap -shared -fPIC wrap.c

void __attribute__((constructor)) say_hi() {
    printf("hi y'all\n");
}

void __attribute__((destructor)) say_bye() {
    printf("bye y'all\n");
}
```

Destructor runs with `main.c`:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./wrap ./main
hi y'all
main
bye y'all
```

Destructor doesn't run with `/bin/ls`:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./wrap /bin/ls
hi y'all
main  main.c  wrap  wrap.c
```

I can't work out how to debug this. `LD_DEBUG=all` doesn't show anything useful. `ldd main` and `ldd /bin/ls` look comparable. Both binaries are dynamically linked. The [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) don't list any caveats I should be aware of, as far as I can see.

Comment: Your destructor probably runs, and it could be that you don't see it because standard output was closed. Try adding something like `open("path/to/bogus/file/that/does/not/exist/foo/bar", O_RDONLY);` in your destructor and see if that appears in the output of `strace env LD_PRELOAD=./wrap /bin/ls`. If not, then `ls` might be exiting early with `_Exit()` or `_exit()`, which do not run destructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, [GNU `ls` closes `stdout` before it exits](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/f45ab30c0b627099fedf57946a469f8d29a32915/src/ls.c#L1658), via an `atexit` handler that presumably gets run before your destructor.

So probably your destructor runs just fine, but doesn't print anything because you are writing to a stream that is closed.

You'll probably need to have your destructor, and your wrapper in general, do its logging in some more robust fashion.  Opening a raw fd and `write()`ing to it would be better, but even so, some programs will do `for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++) close(i);` which would close your log fd as well.  The only really safe way might be to `open/write/close` every time, or to maintain your own log buffer somewhere in memory and manually write it out when full.

---

From comments, the likely reason is that `stdout` may be directed to a file, and since it is buffered, some of the data may not be written out until the stream is closed.  An error could occur at that point (full disk, I/O error, etc).  If `ls` were to leave the closing of `stdout` to the C library startup/shutdown code as your simple `main.c` does, then this error would go undetected and `ls` would still exit with status 0; there would be no way for the parent process to know that the output file was incomplete.  So by calling `fclose(stdout)` explicitly, `ls` can handle the failure, report it if possible, and exit with nonzero status to ensure that the parent knows not to trust the output.

As ShadowRanger points out, all the GNU coreutils have this behavior.

Comment: *"It's important to detect such failures and exit nonzero because many
   tools (most notably 'make' and other build-management systems) depend
   on being able to detect failure in other tools via their exit status."* As best I can tell they are registering to do this via `atexit` in case they crash for some reason because they *must* fail if something goes wrong so the scripts stop. [source](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/closeout.c#L117). It's worth remembering that crashing is a valid successful exit in many cases.

Comment: Oh, so I bet it's in case you do `ls > somefile`, and `somefile` incurs an I/O error when the stdout buffer is flushed.  By explicitly closing `stdout`, then `ls` has a chance to handle the error or at least exit with nonzero status.

Comment: And to be clear, it's not just `ls`; [all the core utils do this](https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/search?q=close_stdout) (even ones like `cat` that bypass `stdout` in favor of direct use of `STDOUT_FILENO` for everything but argument parsing).

Comment: @NateEldredge based on what I saw on github yes... there were a few exceptions but they were rare. But unlike most programs these *must* have an exit code even if it's just an OOPS because the alternative is worse

Comment: To see that it really is running, doing `dprintf(STDIN_FILENO, "bye y'all\n");` instead will result in the message being printed.